# $.isPlainObject($('...')) == true in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

It doesn't in FF/Chrome and I don't think it should in IE.  after all $() doesn't return a plain object, but an instance of $.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Short Answer:* **no, you're not crazy**, it is indeed a bug in jQuery core.

---

*Long Answer:*

I setup a quick test to see what the difference is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/9J3VP/

The property list differs in it's order in IE (8 at least), so this part ([from jQuery core](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L466)):

```
var key;
for ( key in obj ) { }
```

It grabbing the last property in the list and doing a `hasOwnProperty` check on it, so  it's boiling down to this in IE:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call($(document.body), 'length') //true
```

and this in other browsers (tested FF/Chrome):

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call($(document.body), 'width') //false
```

Since that property list is ordered differently, it's grabbing the `length` property in IE, and something *else* in other browsers, we're getting a different result (for kicks, click to include jQuery UI on the left, watch it change to another custom property, `tabs`).  [This comment above the `for` loop](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L463):

```
// Own properties are enumerated firstly, so to speed up,
// if last one is own, then all properties are own.
```

Is a false assumption about IE's property ordering, so I'd consider this a bug as of jQuery 1.4.2.