# Modify object using jQuery.map?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a key-value pair like

`var classes = { red: 'Red', green: 'Green' };`

How can I prepend each of the keys with a specific value? Could this be done using jQuery.map?

The final result I'm looking for is

`classes = { 'a-red': 'Red', 'a-green': 'Green' };`

Comment: `map` is only for arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
function prependObj(obj, prefix) {
  var result = {};
  for(var i in obj) if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) result[prefix+i] = obj[i];
  return result;
}
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
classes = prependObj(classes, "a-");
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/b9Dc9/).  This does *not* modify the original object and doesn't have any jQuery dependency, so you can use it with or without.

Answer (score 10):

The given answers will work, but they aren't as much fun as using a purely functional construct like $.map.  Here's a purely functional version:

```
$.extend.apply(null, $.map(classes, function(v,k) { var h = {}; h["a-" + k] = v; return h }));
```

This works in two steps: first, the map operates on the key-value pairs of the original object and returns a list of single-valued objects.  Secondly, the [$.extend function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) combines these all together into a single object; the [.apply method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is used to pass the arguments to the function as an array.

Unfortunately, the lack of a nice way to make object literals with variable key names makes this kind of ugly, and it's possibly not as efficient, but is a a nifty one-liner!

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to use jQuery to take care of the loop, you could use `$.each()`.

You can't really modify the existing key, but you can replace the key/value pair with a new set that has the new key and the old value, and delete the old set.

```
var classes = { red: 'Red', green: 'Green' };
var newClasses = {};

$.each( classes, function( key,val ) {
    newClasses["a-" + key] = val;
});
```

Or with a regular `for` loop:

```
var classes = { red: 'Red', green: 'Green' };
var newClasses = {};

for( var name in classes ) {
    if( classes.hasOwnProperty( name ) )
        newClasses["a-" + key] = classes[name];
});
```

```
var classes = { red: 'Red', green: 'Green' };

$.each( classes, function( key,val ) {
    classes["a-" + key] = val;
    delete classes[key];
});
```

**EDIT:** If you wanted to keep the original, or if there's an issue in some browsers with an infinite loop (I'm testing...) do this:

Comment: Wouldn't this result in an endless loop?

Comment: @Nick - It doesn't in Safari, but good point. I guess I'll give it a test in IE.

Comment: Will this modify the original array?

Comment: @Adam - Yes. It is adding new keys/values, and deleting the old one. Did you want to keep the original?

Comment: @patrick - It locks up IE with an out of memory exception here. @Alin - test things like this in all browsers, don't assume...also it does *not* operate on a copy.

Comment: @Nick - Indeed I should have tested first. Especially since the [spec](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.6.4) seems to leave open the possibility of enumeration of properties added during a `for/in`. *"If new properties are added to the object being enumerated during enumeration, the newly added properties are not guaranteed to be visited in the active enumeration."* I wonder why it isn't required to be one way or the other. Seems that both IE and Safari are in compliance.

Comment: @patrick - I think it's because order of enumeration isn't guaranteed, it actually causes some issues elsewhere too, let me see if I can find the question this came up on a while back. *Edit:* Here it is, same root issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399649/isplainobject-true-in-ie

Comment: @Nick - Well that would make sense. I remember that question when it came up. Thanks for the link (and reminder). :o)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that javascript has closures:

```
var classes = { red: 'Red', green: 'Green' };
var prefixedClasses = {}
$.map(classes, function(v, k) {
 prefixedClasses['a-' + k] = v;
});
```

should do it.